# How to grab numerical values form certain block of values in R

Tags: r, filter, extract

I have a df dataframe as below.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 X1 = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,3,4,4,4),
                 X2 = c(1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23),
                 X3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X4 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 X5 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X6 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X7 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X8 = c(1,1,0,2,8,0,1,3,4,5),
                 X9 = c(5,2,3,5,7,6,1,3,1,1),
                 X10 = c(1,2,1,4,0,6,7,5,5,6),
                 X11 = c(4,0,6,7,8,0,0,0,7,6),
                 X12 = c(0,1,0,0,0,6,5,4,0,0),
                 X13 = c(1,0,3,4,3,2,1,7,8,7),
                 X14 = c(1,2,NA,4,5,7,8,NA,8,5),
                 X15 = c(2,6,NA,6,5,NA,3,NA,NA,3))

> df
   id X1   X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15
1   1  1 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  1  5   1   4   0   1   1   2
2   2  2 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  1  2   2   0   1   0   2   6
3   3  3 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  0  3   1   6   0   3  NA  NA
4   4  4 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  2  5   4   7   0   4   4   6
5   5  2 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  8  7   0   8   0   3   5   5
6   6  2 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  0  6   6   0   6   2   7  NA
7   7  3 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   7   0   5   1   8   3
8   8  4 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  3  3   5   0   4   7  NA  NA
9   9  4 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  4  1   5   7   0   8   8  NA
10 10  4 1.23  0  1  0  0  0  5  1   6   6   0   7   5   3
```

For each id, starting from column `X5` to until `X7` or `X8`, there is a block of 3 or 4 `0`s. After this block, I need to grab the numerical values until the next `0`.

My desired output would be:

```
> df_new
   id Gamma1 Gamma2 Gamma3 Gamma4
1   1      1      5      1      4
2   2      1      2      2     NA
3   3      3      1      6     NA
4   4      2      5      4      7
5   5      8      7     NA     NA
6   6      6      6     NA     NA
7   7      1      1      7     NA
8   8      3      3      5     NA
9   9      4      1      5      7
10 10      5      1      6      6
```

Comment: You should clarify better *exactly* what you want, but I think basically this: 1) since x5 thru x7 are always zero, grab the subset `df[,9:16]` .   2) for each row,  `zer = which(this_row == 0)` .  3)  `newrow <- this_row[(zer[1]+1):(zer[2]+1)]`  .   4) lengthen each `newrow` by appending `NA` as desired.   But if a row doesn't have a zero later on,  you'll have to put in some safety checks for that.

Comment: Geepers, NONE of the answers supplied took advantage of my `zer[1:2]` method :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the condition always starts at column "X5" (column 6), using `pivot_longer` with a consecutive `pivot_wider` to construct the desired data frame.

Explanation: With condition `== 0` starting at the desired column, a subsequent `consecutive_id` always gives the expected sequence of numbers on id 3.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  mutate(cons_id = row_number() > 4 & value == 0, 
         cons_id = consecutive_id(cons_id) == 3, .by = id) %>% 
  filter(cons_id) %>% 
  mutate(name = paste0("Gamma", row_number()), .by = id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=id)
# A tibble: 10 × 5
      id Gamma1 Gamma2 Gamma3 Gamma4
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1      1      5      1      4
 2     2      1      2      2     NA
 3     3      3      1      6     NA
 4     4      2      5      4      7
 5     5      8      7     NA     NA
 6     6      6      6     NA     NA
 7     7      1      1      7     NA
 8     8      3      3      5     NA
 9     9      4      1      5      7
10    10      5      1      6      6
```

Answer (score 2):

This will probably error out if there isn't a subsequent 0, but it works on your input:

```
mat = df[-(1:5)] |> as.matrix()

result = apply(mat, 1, \(x) {
  # drop leading 0s
  x = tail(x, -(match(TRUE, x != 0) - 1))
  # keep until first 0
  x = head(x, match(TRUE, x == 0) - 1)
  unname(x)
})

## pad the lengths
n = max(lengths(result))
result = lapply(result, \(x) {length(x) = n; x})

## put in a data frame and label
result = do.call(rbind, result)
colnames(result) = paste0("Gamma", 1:ncol(result))
result = cbind(df["id"], result)
result
#    id Gamma1 Gamma2 Gamma3 Gamma4
# 1   1      1      5      1      4
# 2   2      1      2      2     NA
# 3   3      3      1      6     NA
# 4   4      2      5      4      7
# 5   5      8      7     NA     NA
# 6   6      6      6     NA     NA
# 7   7      1      1      7     NA
# 8   8      3      3      5     NA
# 9   9      4      1      5      7
# 10 10      5      1      6      6
```

Answer (score 1):

It's admittedly a bit clunky but it works:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 X1 = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,3,4,4,4),
                 X2 = c(1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23,1.23),
                 X3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X4 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 X5 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X6 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X7 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 X8 = c(1,1,0,2,8,0,1,3,4,5),
                 X9 = c(5,2,3,5,7,6,1,3,1,1),
                 X10 = c(1,2,1,4,0,6,7,5,5,6),
                 X11 = c(4,0,6,7,8,0,0,0,7,6),
                 X12 = c(0,1,0,0,0,6,5,4,0,0),
                 X13 = c(1,0,3,4,3,2,1,7,8,7),
                 X14 = c(1,2,NA,4,5,7,8,NA,8,5),
                 X15 = c(2,6,NA,6,5,NA,3,NA,NA,3))

df %>% 
  # select relevant cols
  dplyr::select(id, X5:ncol(df)) %>% 
  # reshape to long
  tidyr::pivot_longer(2:ncol(.)) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>% 
  # create "cut" by getting first zero after a non-zero
  dplyr::mutate(first_zero = (value == 0 & value < dplyr::lag(value, default = F))) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cut = cumsum(first_zero)) %>% 
  # only keep non-zero values up until first zero thereafter
  dplyr::filter(cut < 1 & value != 0) %>% 
  # create group index
  dplyr::mutate(group = as.factor(dplyr::row_number())) %>% 
  # fill up missings because of differing group sizes
  tidyr::complete(id, group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(group = paste0("Gamma", 1:4)) %>% 
  # clean and reshape back
  dplyr::select(-first_zero, -cut, -name) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 10 × 5
#>       id Gamma1 Gamma2 Gamma3 Gamma4
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1      1      5      1      4
#>  2     2      1      2      2     NA
#>  3     3      3      1      6     NA
#>  4     4      2      5      4      7
#>  5     5      8      7     NA     NA
#>  6     6      6      6     NA     NA
#>  7     7      1      1      7     NA
#>  8     8      3      3      5     NA
#>  9     9      4      1      5      7
#> 10    10      5      1      6      6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

fet us first consider your desired output. Since you don't know how many numbers greater than 0 will come, the actual output are vectors of different length. You have cast them in a data frame and filled out with NA's, which is OK, but I would do that as a separate step.

Second, how about we write a function that takes a vector and extracts the
first non-zero run in that vector. We can use `rle` for that:

```
## create a function which returns first non-zero run of a vector
first_non_zero_run <- function(vec) {

  vec_rle <- rle(vec)
  if(vec_rle$values[1] == 0) {
    vec_rle$values[1] <- NA
    vec_rle$lengths[1] <- 1
  }

  sel <- which(vec_rle$values == 0)[1]
  
  if(!is.na(sel)) {
    vec_rle$values[sel:length(vec_rle$values)] <- NA
    vec_rle$lengths[sel:length(vec_rle$lengths)] <- 1
  }

  ret <- inverse.rle(vec_rle)
  ret <- ret[ !is.na(ret) ]
  ret
}
```

Here is how it works: we first run-length encode the vector. The result is
a list with two members: values and lengths. The values member contains the
values of the vector, and the lengths member contains the number of times
each value was repeated. This makes it easy for us to get rid of the first
run of 0's and also find the next one.

Then we do the following:

```
## select columns from df from X5 to the last column using tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% select(X5:last_col())

## or, in base R
df2 <- df[ , which(colnames(df) == "X5"):ncol(df)]

vecs <- apply(df2, 1, first_non_zero_run)
```

OK, you basically have what you need, but to get the result as a
respectable data frame we need to pad each vector with NA's.

```
max_length <- max(sapply(vecs, length))

## expand each vector to max_length
vecs <- lapply(vecs, \(x) { c(x, rep(NA, max_length - length(x))) })

## combine the vectors into a matrix
result <- reduce(vecs, rbind)

## turn it into a data frame and add the id column
result <- data.frame(df$id, result)
```